# I keep getting "Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" but I checked out the statement using mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
try{
    Staff.aggregate(
            {$group:{_id:{name:"$name",age:'$age'},total:{$sum:1}}}, 
            {$match:{total:{$gt:1}}}
    , modelHelper.mergeStaffCallBack);
}catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```

This is the equivalent query in mongoshell.

```
db.staffs.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id:{name:"$name",age:'$age'},
            total:{$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
             total:{ $gt: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

It executed successfully. I cannot spot the error in my nodejs code above. The catch caught the error

> "Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators".

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: See the difference with the `[]` structure. You also need to consider how your `function` evaluates in this context. Those are the things you need to fix.

Comment: My apologies. But I do not know what you meant. With reference to [Mongoose API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate), the example did not use the [] brackets.

Comment: I managed a work around by using their aggregation pipeline builder. But I would still like to know where I went wrong. I stuck my eyes on the screen and compared against the working shell method. I just cannot see it!

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline stages are separate BSON documents in the array:

this is correct

```
try{
Staff.aggregate(
        [{$group:{_id:{name:"$name",age:'$age'},total:{$sum:1}}}, 
        {$match:{total:{$gt:1}}}]
, modelHelper.mergeStaffCallBack);
}catch (err) {


console.log(err);}
```